# Missing full stop in privileges area

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, grammar

I have just noticed that there is a missing full stop at the end of [this sentence](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) (the last one):

[image]

And as it is really bugging me, I thought that I would report it.

Although I give my example as AU, this issue applies SE-wide.

**Clarification:**

It currently looks like this:

> Privileges control what you can do on Ask Ubuntu. Gain more privileges
> by increasing your reputation (points you receive from your fellow
> users for posting helpful questions and answers)

However it should look like this (a full stop needs to be at the end of the last sentence):

> Privileges control what you can do on Ask Ubuntu. Gain more privileges
> by increasing your reputation (points you receive from your fellow
> users for posting helpful questions and answers)**.**

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is missing and where? Can you explain with clear text and how it *should* be written? I honestly can't see anything wrong.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I have updated my question with a clarification of that.

Comment: allow 6 to 8 weeks to get fixed, until then use this `$('div.page-description > p').text($('div.page-description > p').text() +'.');`

Comment: I didn't know that a full stop is required after brackets. Honestly, never used it myself.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I think [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/1230) explains its proper usage quite well.

Comment: @rene: Or use this user style: `body.privileges-page .page-description p:after { content: ' .'; margin-left: -0.2em; }`

Comment: That can be part of SOUP ...I'll keep that kind of css wizardry in mind for the next time ;)  @IlmariKaronen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since bugs like that are obviously of the highest priority, this will be fixed in the next build (build rev `2015.9.21.3704` on MSE/MSO, `2015.9.21.2834` on sites).